# Microsoft JScript runtime error while running gulp command

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp

**While running gulp code in CMD  :**

```
    "use strict";

    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var connect = require('gulp-connect'); //Runs a local dev server
    var open = require('gulp-open'); //Open a URL in a web browser

    var config = {
        port: 9005,
        devBaseUrl: 'http://localhost',
        paths: {
            html: './src/*.html',
            dist: './dist'
        }
    }

    //Start a local development server
    gulp.task('connect', function() {
        connect.server({
            root: ['dist'],
            port: config.port,
            base: config.devBaseUrl,
            livereload: true
        });
    });

    gulp.task('open', ['connect'], function() {
        var options = {
            uri: config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/',
            app: 'chrome'
        };
        gulp.src('dist/index.html')
            .pipe(open(options));
    });

    gulp.task('html', function() {
        gulp.src(config.paths.html)
            .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
            .pipe(connect.reload());
    });

gulp.task('default', ['html', 'open']);
```

[image]

*As per the initial analysis, JS file open in IE default so I tried changing  tools>Internet Options>Advanced tab, uncheck "Display notification about every script error"
Still getting the error.*

Comment: Doesn't `gulp` require that you run it on Node?

Comment: I tried running with command `node gulp` still no luck, unable to start the server.